# Was the Leahy act ever used against Israel?

Tags: united-states, israel

> The term “Leahy law” refers to two statutory provisions prohibiting
> the U.S. Government **from using funds for assistance to units of
> foreign security forces where there is credible information
> implicating that unit in the commission of gross violations of human
> rights (GVHR).** One statutory provision applies to the State Department
> and the other applies to the Department of Defense. The State
> Department Leahy law was made permanent under section 620M of the
> Foreign Assistance Act of 1961, 22 U.S.C. 2378d. The U.S. government
> considers torture, extrajudicial killing, enforced disappearance, and
> rape under color of law as GVHRs when implementing the Leahy law.
> Incidents are examined on a fact-specific basis. The State Department
> Leahy law includes an exception permitting resumption of assistance to
> a unit if the Secretary of State determines and reports to Congress
> that the government of the country is taking effective steps to bring
> the responsible members of the security forces unit to justice.

https://www.state.gov/key-topics-bureau-of-democracy-human-rights-and-labor/human-rights/leahy-law-fact-sheet/

Was the Leahy act ever used against Israel? The Leahy act seem to state that American military aid cannot be used to commit "gross" violations of human rights, I am wondering if this legal provision was ever used against Israel. I am guessing it has never been used, because the word "gross" is being used and the U.S. has always affirmed Israel's right to defend itself.